# ASP.Net MVC: So wait... The Default Route Parameter Has To Be Named id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Has anyone else had this issue?  I have to be doing something wrong.

So I'm setting up a route for errors like this:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
 "SharedError",
 "Shared/Error/{error}",
 new { error = "" }
);
```

And calling like:

```
return parentController.RedirectToRoute("SharedError", new RouteValueDictionary(new { error = errorMessage.ToString() }));
```

And on the controller:

```
public ActionResult Error(String error)
```

Simple right?  Well when this is actually run, error is null despite the url looking like:

/Shared/Error/ThisIsTheError

But the error parameter in the Error method is null.  (And yes I've tried other words)

Now if I replace all that with the word 'id' everything works.

Global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute
(
 "SharedError",
 "Shared/Error/{id}",
 new { id = "" }
);
```

Redirect:

```
return parentController.RedirectToRoute("SharedError", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = errorMessage.ToString() }));
```

Shared Controller:

```
public ActionResult Error(String id)
```

Is id a must have word for all routes if you have a default route taking in a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always need to specify the controller and action parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
 "SharedError",
 "Shared/Error/{error}",
 new { controller = "Shared", action="Error", error = "" }
);
```

I'm guessing that the reason why using id works for you is because you have the default route still registered, which has id as a parameter and default values for controller and action.

Note, if you still have the default route, make sure you add your route **before** it, otherwise it will match the other one first.

Comment: Right, but it should be new { controller="Shared", action="Error", error = "" }

Comment: Corrected (although I don't think the OP mentioned what his controller name was).

Comment: @programmin: see my note at the end, if that was your problem.

Comment: also make sure you have controller and action set correctly, in the example i just made them up

Comment: Ahhh your note might be it.  Checking.